# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects - MCEdit

Tags: python, typeerror, mcedit

I have this:

```
    rotValues = '[rx='+ rotx + ',' + "ry=" + roty +"]"
```

It gives me the error shown in the title, help please!

Comment: You should take a look at string interpolation or string formatting. Both will make it easy to print floats with a certain precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another (and much better way) of doing this is to use the `str.format` method:

```
>>> rotx, roty = 5.12, 6.76
>>> print '[rx={},ry={}]'.format(rotx, roty)
[rx=5.12,ry=6.76]
```

You can also specify the precision using `format`:

```
>>> print '[rx={0:.1f},ry={1:.2f}]'.format(rotx, roty)
[rx=5.1,ry=6.76]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to concatenate a string with floats. Python, being a strongly typed language will not allow that. Therefore, you have to convert the `rotx` and `roty` values to strings as follows:

`rotValues = '[rx='+ str(rotx) + ',' + "ry=" + str(roty) +"]"`

If you want your values (`rotx` and `roty`) to have a certain precision in decimal points, you can do:

`rotValues = '[rx='+ str(round(rotx,3)) + ',' + "ry=" + str(round(roty,3)) +"]"`

```
>>> rotx = 1234.35479334
>>> str(round(rotx, 5))
'1234.35479'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
>>> rotValues = '[rx='+ str(rotx) + ',' + "ry=" + str(roty) +"]" 
>>> print rotValues
[rx=1.0,ry=2.0]
```